# Ruby on Rails search with array of values to find in multiple fields (datatables)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, datatables

I implemented datatables like proposed on the http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables and it works just fine. Unfortunately it doesnt concern the point of searching with spaces in the input field. If I implement it with the search function processing it with javascript it works just fine.

So what I want to do is search on the database on many fields where the parameters of the sql are splitted by space (dynamic size of parameters)
eg. "name1 street city" -> this means returned objects must contain all three "name1", "street", "city" in one of the objects fields.

Here's an example:
Person :name, :address, :city, :country

Person("Peter Mayer", "Some Street 111", "New York", "United States")

- if a user searches with "Peter York" it should find the object
- if a user searches with "Peter Los Angeles" it should not find anything
- if a user searches with "111 Mayer States York" it should find the object

okey, i could write many different sql's respecting the amount of params but that istn't so nice

Is there an easy way to solve that?

Filtering after searching with just the first param isn't an option since pagination wouldnt work anymore

Comment: Consider using a full-blown search gem like PgSearch https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Join all the attributes that must be found in one string

   `search_attributes = [person.name1, person.address, person.city, person.country].join(' ')`
   for your example `search_attributes` would be equal to `"Peter Mayer Some Street 111 New York United States"`
2. Then you iterate over every string in the query and make sure it is found in `search_attributes` using `.include?`, and return a record only if all strings in the sent query are found in `search_attributes`

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this now:

```
searchData = params[:sSearch].split(" ")

searchString = "1 = 1"
searchParams = {}
i = 0
searchData.each do |searchParam|
    searchString += " AND (persons.name like :search"+i.to_s+" or persons.address like
     :search"+i.to_s+" or persons.city like :search"+i.to_s+" or persons.country like    
     :search"+i.to_s+"+")"

    searchParams["search#{i}".to_sym] = "%"+searchParam+"%"
    i += 1
end

Person.where(searchString, searchParams)
```